# Trigger event with a href class and containing span class Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to perform a trigger event with Google Tag Manager.

I have a link like so:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="unique-class"><span class="not-unique-class">Click me</span></a>
```

How can I make Google Tag Manager to trigger both "unique-class" and "not-unique-class"?

UDATED TEXT BELOW TO MAKE THINGS MORE CLEAR:

Here is the code:

```
<div class="fusion-button-wrapper">
        <a class="fusion-button button-flat button-round button-large button-default button-1 unique-class" target="_self" href="http://www.example.com/"><span class="fusion-button-text">Go to page</span></a>
    </div>
```

In the preview mode I get the following variables when I clock on the SPAN element:

- _event ->  'gtm.click'
- Click Classes -> 'fusion-button-text'
- Click Element -> [object HTMLSpanElement]
- Click ID -> ''
- Click Target -> ''
- Click Text -> 'GO TO PAGE'
- Click URL -> ''
- Event -> 'gtm.click'
- Form Classes -> 'fusion-button-text'
- Form Element -> [object HTMLSpanElement]
- Form ID  -> ''
- Form Target  -> ''
- Form Text -> 'GO TO PAGE'
- Form URL -> ''
- Page Hostname -> 'example.com'
- Page Path '/examplepage/'
- Page URL 'http://example.com/examplepage'
- Referrer ''

When I click on the a link element I get the following variables
 - Variable -> 'gtm.click'
 - Click Classes -> 'fusion-button button-flat button-round button-large button-default button-1 uni que-class'
 - Click Element -> http://www.example.com/
 - Click ID -> ''
 - Click Target -> '_self'
 - Click Text -> 'GO TO PAGE'
 - Click URL -> 'http://www.example.com/'
 - Event -> 'gtm.click'
 - Form Classes -> 'fusion-button button-flat button-round button-large button-default button-1 uni que-class'
 - Form Element -> http://www.example.com/
 - Form ID  -> ''
 - Form Target  -> '_self'
 - Form Text -> 'GO TO PAGE'
 - Form URL -> 'http://www.example.com/'
 - Page Hostname -> 'example.com'
 - Page -> '/prenumerera/'
 - Page URL -> 'http://www.example.com/'
 - Referrer -> ''

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score 0):

You can use those classes in a trigger like this, if you are requiring either or:

[image]

or like this if you require both classes:

[image]

Also, if you go into GTM preview mode and click on your link, you'll see both the `gtm.click` and `gtm.linkClick` events. You can then look at the dataLayer to see what you can use in your trigger. There are several options, I would think.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was hard! :( I simply can't make this to work properly. I can get trigger to fire upon the unique class (I click on that area). The span that's ontop of the unique a href class won't trigger at all when I look in analytics. I really need that klick on the span to trigger as well. I have more buttons like this on the page with other unique-classes but with containing spans that have the same not-unique-class. Any ideas? I follow your example.

Comment: Did you do what i suggested and click on your link in preview mode, and check the gtm.click and gtm.linkClick variables, like `Click Classes`? Seeing the classes indicates that the link registered with both the span element as well as the anchor element.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I have updated my post. Will this clear things up a little bit? :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the trigger type choise - **Just links**

**Just links** trigger tracks only link clicks.

**All elements** trigger tracks clicks of elements that were actually clicked, regardless of whether they have a link or not (e.g. image, website background, button text, etc.